# Getting the correct bounds of UIViewController's view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, rotation, bounds

I have an iPad-application. In landscape orientation the `UIViewController`'s view actual width = `1024px` and height = 768 - 20 (statusBar) - 44 (navigationBar) = `704px`.

So I wanna get this `[1024 x 704]` size and I'm using `self.view.bounds` for it. It returns `[748 x 1024]`, which is wrong! But when I rotate the screen twice (current -> portrait -> current), the view's bounds are correct - `[1024 x 704]`.

The view was initialized like this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

And bounds were get like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
}
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    NSLog(@"bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
}
```

So the question is.. How can I get the correct view's bound in the very beginning?

Comment: In my case using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` worked but had a delay (about one second) that I didn't like. I tried `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and it worked properly. Keep in mind that viewDidLayoutSubviews may be triggered multiple times depending on what you do with your subviews so you may need some extra checks. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews

Comment: @MohsenHK Hi – The situation you describe does not seem to make sense. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called after `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, so it can't have any less delay. Does that make sense? I suggest that the delay that you encountered must be due to something else going on – perhaps an interaction with animation?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## How to do this correctly

Your `UIViewController` subclass should override the method `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, [see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16421170/2547229).

When this method is called, the viewController's `view` has its correct size and you can make any necessary adjustments to subviews prior to the layout pass over the subviews.

#### Swift

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    NSLog("bounds = \(self.view.bounds)")
}
```

#### Obj-C

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
}
```

## Documentation

> **When a view's bounds change**, the view adjusts the position of its subviews. Your view controller can override this method to make changes before the view lays out its subviews. The default implementation of this method does nothing.

As you see from the emphasised part, this method is called *every time* the view controller's view changes size, as well as when the view first appears. This lets you respond correctly to rotation and other bounds change events

## Several ways that don't work

A few approaches suggested in other answers don't work well, or have serious drawbacks. I urge you to avoid these approaches and I'll go through them to discuss the reasons you should avoid them.

- `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` – during these calls `view` does not yet have its final size. **The  size you get will only ever be correct by pure chance**, so as to mislead you.
- `viewDidAppear` – this is too late. **Your view is already on screen and visible to the user**. Making changes here will cause visible changes / abrupt glitches and will look amateurish. Once again, please – for your sake, for my sake, for *everyone's* sake: don't do it! You're better than that and so are your users.
- `UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size` – this is *extremely* low level. You're implementing a `UIViewController` and the size of its view depends on the controllers it is nested in (navigation, tab, paging, any custom controllers, etc), how the device is rotated, and potentially, how the screen has been split up for multitasking. So, while you *might* be able to compensate for all these and calculate the final size of your view, you'll end up with complex and brittle code that can easily break if Apple decide to change any of these metrics. `UIViewController` will do all this for you if you just override `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Other than not providing correct information, these problematic approaches will not help you with auto-rotation or other events that cause the view controller's view to change size, such as multitasking gestures. This is something you really want to handle smoothly.

So please: be a champ. Do it the right way. Use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.  Your implementation will be called for every size change, and your users, future self and team members will celebrate you for it. Bravo!

## Further tips

**When** `viewWillLayoutSubviews`  is called, **the only view** in your hierarchy that will be resized to its final size is `viewController.view`. The give away for this is in the name of the method. It's telling you `view…` (your view controller's root `view`) *`…WillLayout…`* (really soon now, but it's not happened *yet*) `…Subviews` (everything else in its hierarchy under the root view).

So subview layout has not happened yet. *Every* child under the root *does not* yet have a valid *final* size. Any size information you query from the child views will be **at best** completely wrong.

More likely, **and enormously worse**, it will be **misleadingly correct**.

It *happens* to be what you expect and need due to a default at this size and orientation, or due to your storyboard settings. But this is only by chance and isn't something you can rely on with different device sizes or orientations.

If you need to be told when a particular subview changes size, and know its exact final size, you should generally override the `layoutSubviews` method of that particular `UIView` subclass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To clarify, are you saying if we want to know the size of a subview that is of class `UIView`, the only way to properly do so is to override its `layoutSubviews` method (which would require creating a custom class)?

Comment: @Crashalot Overriding makes sense for a subclass that lays out its children. However, it can be problematic if you often want to compose this behaviour rather than override an existing view class. An approach I've taken is to create a specific `UIView` subclass, `BoundsSenderView`, that _only_ has the behaviour of forwarding `layoutSubviews` to some injected `boundsListener` handler. It doesn't display anything or respond to touch, etc. You can then use auto layout to pin it on to the view that you want the size of, and you'll get the callback when this changes size.

Comment: There might be other ways to get the size of a subview after layout, but I'm not aware of them. You'd need to hook in to the complete layout pass having finished.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's so frustrating that Apple makes this difficult.

Answer (score 34):

As per some of the other answers, the issue you are seeing is because `viewDidLoad` is called **before** the rotation happens.  Because the iPad always initializes in portrait mode, if you get the size values in `viewDidLoad`, they will always be the portrait sizes - this is irrespective of any orientations you've configured.

To get the size **after** the orientation/rotation happens, get the size values in `viewDidAppear`.

---

I don't particularly understand why iOS doesn't handle this better - especially given that you define the orientations in the project settings, and, in Xcode Interface Builder.  But, I'm sure there is a good reason ;-).

Comment: If you are creating heavy views ,there can be delay in view appearance , you can reduce the delay by using `viewWillAppear`

Comment: I tried viewWillAppear.  It does not work as desired.  Seems that the bounds calculation is done after the view has appeared.

Comment: I strongly recommend **not** to use `viewDidAppear`. Your view is on screen and visible to the user by this point and changes you make will can cause abrupt and visible glitches. It also won't help you respond to changes of view size during rotation (etc).  [Instead, use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42275589/2547229) (disclosure: links to my answer) which is the way iOS handlers this.

Comment: viewDidAppear won't work if user make a rotation after it did appear. correct answer is from @Benjohn viewWillLayoutSubviews will called everytimes when you either rotate it or not

Answer (score 16):

I've always used:

```
CGSize sizeOfScreen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

to get the size of the screen, and:

```
CGSize sizeOfView = self.view.bounds.size;
```

to get the `view`'s size. I have just tested it on viewDidLoad and it returned:

```
2012-07-17 10:25:46.562 Project[3904:15203] bounds = {768, 1004}
```

Which is correct since the CGSize is defined as {Width, Height}.

Comment: That's odd. The fact that you are getting the size in viewDidLoad shouldn't matter because the view "is already loaded"

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found in my last project: the frame of self.view will be adjusted after viewDidLoad according to if this screen has navigation bar etc.

So maybe you want to use that value after viewDidLoad (maybe in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear) or adjust it manually by substract the height of bars.

Comment: I'm already using it in `viewDidLoad` method and after it. And bounds stay wrong until I rotate the screen. Manual subtracting is bad solution, because application is targeted for all devices & orientations..

Comment: Will did you using it after viewDidLoad? In my case, viewDidAppear will return right size.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and found that getting the bounds in `viewDidAppear` worked for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get correct bounds of view in `ViewDidLoad` method, you can use Dispatch async with delay for it. See this example below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                // Get your bounds here
            }
```