# How do I get the size of a UIView from within the View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Inside the `viewDidLoad` method of a UIViewController:

```
NSLog(@"frame: %f %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

With the device in landscape:

```
frame: 748.000000 1024.000000
```

With the device in portrait:

```
frame: 768.000000 1004.000000
```

Comment: Are you using sotryboards for creating the VC ?

Comment: No, I alloc init it in code.

Comment: Can you post the alloc init code for your VC ? And if you are using .xib files, check the size of the view in xib file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, the frame may not have adjusted to all of the things that affect its final size, such as rotation, status bar height changes, other views, etc.  It's generally best to only create and set up your objects here; you can inspect the finalized frame in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called every time the view rotates. Rotation is my next problem, and setting up the frame there causes it to jump, unlike the smooth autorotation that safari has.

Comment: You can also animate the changes in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation` to avoid that jumping.

Answer (score 5):

There is no size of the a view controller. Its the size of the view or the window.
you can use the `.frame` or `.bounds` method to get it. 
Also you can easily print the rect using,

```
NSLog("Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
NSLog("Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.window.frame));
```

You can also use the `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` to get the size of the full screen. You will always get that 20 pixel offset in x or y direction, for the status bar, depending on your orientation.

Whatever happens, the frame returns the height and width, assuming the device is in portrait mode, with the home button down. So when the device is in landscape mode, the status bar is on the right side, and the width is 20 pixel less to make room for the status bar.

Edited: After iOS 8
Now you get the width and height correctly in portrait and landscape orientation. i.e. as it looks -- in landscape width=portrait height. When I use in my code,

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    CGSize size = frame.size;
    if (![UIUtil isAfterIOS8]){
        size.width = frame.size.height;
        size.height = frame.size.width;
    }

/* UIUtil.m */ 
+ (BOOL) isAfterIOS8 {
    return [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0;
}
```

Comment: Note the "width" of 748 with the device in landscape. This is one of his issues.

Comment: Whatever happens, the frame returns the height and width, assuming the device is in portrait mode, with the home button down. So when the device is in landscape mode, the status bar is on the right side, and the width is 20 pixel less to make room for the status bar.

Comment: Right, but why rotate everything 90º in your head when you can just wait for the frame to be set up properly/

Answer (score 3):

You should use `self.view.bounds` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can log it as :

```
NSLog(@"My view's frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(myView.frame));
```

Or try this

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);
```

Or

```
CGFloat height = [self.view frame].size.height;
CGFloat width = [self.view frame].size.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the current size of the main view in your view controller. The views are measured in points.

Note that the size of the iPad screen in points is 1024x768, but the size you are getting in the NSLog is without the status bar on top, which is 20 points tall.

Comment: Note the "width" of 748 with the device in landscape.  This is one of his issues.  Also, the views are measured in points, not pixels.