# UIViewController viewDidLoad incorrect width/height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Everybody knows that you can't trust the frame size on a UIViewController init/viewDidLoad method; this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad: {
     NSLog(@"%d", self.view.frame.size.width);
}
```

will print wrong sizes in many occasions (in particular it's pretty much broken in landscape mode)

This will actually return always corrected results so it's good to layout the subviews:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear: {
     NSLog(@"%d", self.view.frame.size.width);
}
```

The problem is that viewWillAppears gets called every time the view appears, so it's not suitable to alloc or add subviews. So you end up declaring **every single view**  in the interface and you end up with huge header files that I don't like at all since most of the items don't need any more manipulations after the initial setup.

So question one is: **Is there a better way to handle subviews positioning?**

Question two is very related, let's say I have a subclass of UIView including various others subviews. I declare it inside my interface, and i alloc/init it in my init/viewDidLoad method.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    ...
    menu = [[SNKSlidingMenu alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    ...
}
```

As we already know we now need to reposition it in viewWillAppear to get a more accurate reading

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    ....
    menu.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    ....
 }
```

The problem is that of course all the subviews needs to be repositioned as well. This is done by the layoutSubviews function that get called automatically, but we got the same problem: **All the subviews need to be declared inside the interface of the SNKSlidingMenu class.. Is there a way around this?**

Thanks.

Comment: use autolayout, or set autoresizing masks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are targetting iOS 5.0 or better you can use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to make changes.

As for your second question, if you need access to an instance variable in other method than `init`, you need to keep it around, I don't see a problem with it.

You can, however, try to use Auto Layouts and set up rules between the subviews so it's automatically laid out for you without the need to keep a reference.

Comment: agreed, but then it's pretty stupid to have to use initWithFrame for initializing every single view. Seems like lots of duplicate code to me, and seems that forces you into using lots of instance variables. Auto layouts are only for newer iOS.

Comment: The old `autoresizingMask` might be enough for you as well. As for duplicate code: if you are duplicating a lot of that code, you can create custom `UIView` subclasses so you don't duplicate, or have helper methods that create the views for you. If you post more code we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 6):

`viewDidLoad` only gets called when your view is *created*, but lots of things can affect the `frame`'s size, and it doesn't get called again when `frame` changes.

Instead:

- create subviews in `viewDidLoad`
- set their sizes in
  `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

See some additional discussion here for handling rotation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16421170/1445366

Answer (score 5):

`viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can resolve this problem.
**But** the two methed would be performed more times.
this is my code to get correct `self.view.frame`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];  
  ...  
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
   // init you view and set it`s frame. this can get correct frame.   
   ...  
  }  
  ...  
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  Albeit, it's kinda ugly as some weird initial view pops up a split second before the dispatch_async kicks in.

For Swift4:

    
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
  }

Answer (score 2):

This saved my life more than once (**Swift 4**):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Basically this forces the viewcontroller to correctly layout it's view and from there you can get the correct frames for all your subviews. This particularly helps when doing transition animations and your view controllers are using autolayout and interface builder.

From what I've noticed it looks like the initial frames are set to whatever your interface builder's default size class is set to. I normally edit using the iPhone XS size class so in `viewDidLoad` it seems that the view's width is always 375 regardless whether you are using an iPhone XR or not. This corrects itself before `viewWillAppear` though.

The above code will correct this issue and allow you to get the correct frames for your view / subviews before the view controller is rendered to the screen.

Comment: Create vc from a xib and see that this doesn't work

Comment: You saved my life. I've been at it since this morning.