# How to place 2 UIButton on UIView programatically with equal width in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I used this code(in UIView class).

```
- (void)setup {

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.12f alpha:1.0f];

    _doneTextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _doneTextButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [_doneTextButton setTitle:@"Save"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_doneTextButton setTitleColor:CODE_A_COLOR forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [_doneTextButton setBackgroundColor:CODE_6_COLOR] ;
    [_doneTextButton.titleLabel setFont:[FontManager getOpenSansBoldFontWithSize:16]];
    [_doneTextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self addSubview:_doneTextButton];
}
```

I am getting this output(buttons at corner).

[image]

I want this "Cancel" and "Save" button exactly fit equally in UIView

[image]

I am using third party lib. and no idea straight logic not working.How do i set frame of both buttons? expecting autoLayout code. thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using autolayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the frame of the buttons to `self.view.frame.size.width/2` and then you can set the second buttons frame by taking the end points of the first button

```
-(void)setup
{
btnSave = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnCancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

btnSave.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-30, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 30);

btnCancel.frame = CGRectMake(btnSave.frame.origin.x+btnSave.frame.size.width+5,  self.view.frame.size.height-30, btnSave.frame.size.width, 30);

btnSave.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[btnSave setTitle:@"Save"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSave setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]] ;
[self.view addSubview:btnSave];

btnCancel.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[btnCancel setTitle:@"Cancel"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnCancel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]] ;
[self.view addSubview:btnCancel];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using autolayout in your Storyboard, so you have to use the layout constraints to achieve this behavior.

Create the button with frame equal to `CGRectZero` and then, in the `updateViewConstraints` method you can create the constraints necessary to setup the buttons' positions. Here is an example:

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    if(!constraintsAdded) {
        [button1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [button2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button1
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:button2
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
        constraintsAdded = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this solution if you're not going with autolayout.

It seems you are going to set width with your view's `frame like self.view.frame.size.width`. In some cases it will return same size which size you defined in xib or storyboard. So that's why its happening, for more info please have a look

[UIViewController viewDidLoad incorrect width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796783/uiviewcontroller-viewdidload-incorrect-width-height)

Please use this solution to get rid such issues.

```
float width  = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height+self.view.frame.origin.y-40, width/2, 40);

self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.cancelButton.frame.size.width+self.cancelButton.frame.origin.x+1, self.view.frame.size.height+self.view.frame.origin.y-40, width/2, 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using UIStackView.and add the two button in the stackview.