# Changing constant of a size-classed constraint within code but it reverts back to storyboard value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I’m running into an issue with constraints that use size classes.

Within the storyboard, I’m setting a view's width constraint to different values for compact width and regular width size classes. Within the view controller, I have a reference to that constraint where I’m setting its constant to zero within `viewDidLoad()`.

The problem that I’m having is that the constant for the constraint reverts back to the storyboard value, except after `viewDidAppear()` gets called. After that point, the constraint constant remains at whatever value I set it to within the source code.

Even setting the constraint's constant to zero within `viewWillAppear()` still leads to the constraint reverting back to the storyboard value.

I can remove the constraint from the storyboard and do it in code, but I was wondering if anyone had any other ideas as to why this is happening and if there is a fix that doesn't involve having to remove the constraint from the storyboard.

Comment: It sounds like it's related to the view lifecycle. Have you tried coding it in a later override? Maybe `viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`? That's the override where you would code against size classes if you weren't using IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess autolayout lays everything out using the default constraints and then lays everything out again, accounting for size classes, before the view appears. That’s why the constraint “reverts” - it’s really just being set to the correct value for the size class for the first time.

Anyways, calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` within `viewDidLoad()` before modifying the constraint solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is an expected behaviour, since a view width is not known at viewDidLoad()

Check out this related answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16421170/7626803